# how to make the eigen tensor's value as the 'if' condition expression

Tags: c++, eigen, tensor

The condition in `if` should be of the boolean type, but I only can get the eigen tensor expression of `compare`. So it comes out the bug when compiling. My question is how I can modify the following code to make the `if` condition legal.

```
Eigen::Tensor<float, 1> linear(2);
linear.setValues({3,4});
auto linear_square = (linear * linear).sum().sqrt();  // linear_square: 5
auto compare = (linear_square>linear_square.constant(4));
if(compare)  // bug: compare cannot be converted to bool
    std::cout<<"hahaha"<<std::endl;
```

Comment: As per documentation eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/unsupported/eigen_tensors.html the output is a boolean tensor. You need to get the element(s) of the tensor and combine the values appropriately. Posting as a comment because I do not have installed Eigen and I cannot check. In your case it is a single boolean so something like compare(0) should be ok

Comment: thanks but still errors like 'no match call (0)'. eigen is not that easy like python

Comment: `compare` has no member named `data`

Answer (score 3):

The main issue is that you used the keyword `auto`, which works in surprising ways for Eigen.

Basically the output of a tensor operation is not a tensor, but an operation, i.e. recipe on how to combine the tensors. When you assign this value (the operation) to a tensor, then, the calculation is triggered. So you need to use tensor as types for the output of your operations, in order to trigger the calculation.

The documentation is a bit more precise than me: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/unsupported/eigen_tensors.html, I quote (emphasis mine):

> Because Tensor operations create tensor operators, the C++ `auto`
>   keyword **does not have its intuitive meaning**. Consider these 2 lines of
>   code:
>
> ```
>     Tensor<float, 3> t3 = t1 + t2;
>     auto t4 = t1 + t2;
> ```
>
> In the first line we allocate the tensor `t3` and it will contain the
>   result of the addition of `t1` and `t2`. In the second line, `t4` is
>   actually the tree of tensor operators that will compute the addition
>   of `t1` and `t2`. In fact, `t4` is not a tensor and you cannot get the
>   values of its elements:
>
> ```
>     Tensor<float, 3> t3 = t1 + t2;
>     cout << t3(0, 0, 0);  // OK prints the value of t1(0, 0, 0) + t2(0, 0, 0)
>
>     auto t4 = t1 + t2;
>     cout << t4(0, 0, 0);  // Compilation error!
> ```

So I avoided using `auto`and I used tensors of rank 0 (the docs tell me that `sum()` returns a rank 0 tensor). This triggered the calculation, making `compare` a real tensor. This code compiles and it runs as expected:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>

int main()
{
    Eigen::Tensor<float, 1> linear{2};
    linear.setValues({ 3,4 });

    //Here you can use auto because you do not try to get data out of this element, I am making explicit the dimensionality
    Eigen::Tensor<float, 0> linear_square = (linear * linear).sum().sqrt();  // linear_square: 5

    //Here you need conversion to Tensor
    Eigen::Tensor<bool, 0> compare = linear_square > linear_square.constant(4);
    if (compare(0)) 
        std::cout << "hahaha" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "no" << std::endl;

}
```

I compiled with MSVC 2019 and I used Eigen 3.3.3 (the one available in NuGet).

Comment: Minor nitpick: `compare(0)` does not require variadic templates, since there is a fall-back implementation for C++03 (I think for up to 5 arguments). But the brace-initialization does not work with C++03, of course: https://godbolt.org/z/M2--DZ

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mistake. Answer edited. I got confused in one of the various #if